# Yii2 wbraganca, File Input (Kartik), dynamic forms

Tags: php, file-io, yii2, dynamicform, kartik-v

Not loaded next preloader and image after insert image in dynamic form item. Correct load image in case I didn't load image yet. In case I load image, next preloader not load in next dynamicform item and I don't save next images
[image]

Comment: add your code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

found one of solution, may be not better, but nearly normal state. 
Problem was here

identifiers[i] = $elem.closest(widgetsOptions[i].widgetItem).index();

if replace this by this:

if(typeof widgetsOptions[i] !== 'undefined'){

identifiers[i] = $elem.closest(widgetsOptions[i].widgetItem).index();
 }

problem was resolved, but not perfectly. After Add new item, preload image loaded correct and I could upload image, but load first item which was has loaded earlier.